# Javafx : I have 2 VBox And I want to put the spacing inbetween them according to hight of other

Tags: javafx

I have Situation I have two VBox named(title_Box,content_Box)  I am putting both VBox inside my Panel. the content of content_Box is not same its vary . so how I can put my title_Box space according to content_Box.
following is I want to achieve.

```
title1
content1....
content2....
title2
content1...
title3
content1..
content2..
content3...
```

so how I can get/set spacing to title_box according to content_Box...
is there any way ..

because I search a lot but everywhere set spacing constant like

```
VBox vb=new Vbox(10);
```

So how I can set it according to another container(VBox) Height.

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean when you said, "my title_Box space according to content_Box"?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha: sure ..both title_Box and content_Box  are the VBox and content of content_Box is not constant or same with respect to hight content_Box had collection of HBox it may be 1,2,3...so Content_Box hight get vary so how i can set title_box item space according to that when i put title_box and content_box on panel..

Comment: @ItachiUchiha : as i shown in example while as question title are the content of title_box and Content are the Content of content_Box and when they put on panel should look like....

Comment: @ItachiUchiha : I am just Update it take look

Comment: Please update your question instead of making edits on the answer. Moreover, you image doesn't make any sense to me. Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha : as show in image title is not exactly associated with its content....not set exactly at same position...where the content

Comment: i want to place  tilte on its content..

Comment: Its still not very clear to me as in which part is the title and which is the content. Can you please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Make `title_Box` and `content_Box` children of a parent VBox container. Then set the vertical grow priority for for content_Box to `Priority.ALWAYS`. This will make sure that the parent vbox will use the priority to allocate additional space if it is resized larger than it's preferred height.

```
VBox.setVgrow(content_Box, Priority.ALWAYS);
```